# I need to know which part of my script needs to be fixed - node.js related

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am writing a node.js web application using mongoose/mongodb.
I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.
I get this error below and there is the code I wrote after.

SyntaxError:

> Unexpected token { in
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/views/fighter/show.ejs while
>   compiling ejs
>       at Function (native)
>       at Object.Template.compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:491:12)
>       at Object.compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:306:16)
>       at handleCache (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:169:18)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:374:14)
>       at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
>       at tryRender (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
>       at EventEmitter.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/app.js:127:17
>       at Query. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3343:16)
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:259:21
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/combatSports/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
>       at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

my code is:

```
<% var significantStrikeLanded = 0; %>
<% var totalTimeinsec  = 0; %>
<% var totalSignificantStrikeLanded = 0; %>
<% var totalSignificantStrikeThrows = 0; %>
<% var totalStrikeAbsorbed  = 0; %>
<% var totalStrikeEnemyThrows = 0; %>
<% var totalStrikeEnemyLanded = 0; %>
<% var totalTakeDowns = 0; %>
<% var totalTakeDownAttempts = 0; %>
<% var totalTakeDownEnemyAttempts = 0; %>
<% var totalTakeDownsEnemyDid = 0; %>
<% var totalSubmissionAttempts = 0; %>
<% var totalWin = 0; %>
<% var totalLoss = 0; %>
<% var totalDraw = 0;%>
<% var timeInsec = 0; %>           
<% var totalNocontest = 0; %>
<% var totalKO = 0; %>
<% var totalSubmission = 0; %>
<% var totalDecision = 0; %>
<% var strikeScoreTotal = 0; %>

    <% fighter.fights.forEach(function(fight) { %>
        <% if (fighter.firstName == fight.fighters[0].fighter.firstName && fighter.lastName == fight.fighters[0].fighter.lastName) { %>




                    <% totalTimeinsec = totalTimeinsec + ((fight.info.round -1)  * 300) + fight.info.min * 60 + fight.info.sec);%> 

                    <% totalSignificantStrikeLanded = totalSignificantStrikeLanded + fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeLanded; %>

                    <% totalSignificantStrikeThrows = totalSignificantStrikeThrows + fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeThrow; %>

                    <% totalStrikeAbsorbed = totalStrikeAbsorbed + fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeLanded; %>

                    <% totalStrikeEnemyThrows = totalStrikeEnemyThrows + fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeThrow; %>

                    <% totalStrikeEnemyLanded = totalStrikeEnemyLanded + fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeLanded; %>

                    <% totalTakeDowns = totalTakeDowns + fight.fighters[0].takeDowns; %>

                    <% totalTakeDownAttempts = totalTakeDownAttempts + fight.fighters[0].takeDownAttempts; %>

                    <% totalTakeDownEnemyAttempts = totalTakeDownEnemyAttempts + fight.fighters[1].takeDownAttempts; %>

                    <% totalTakeDownsEnemyDid = totalTakeDownsEnemyDid + fight.fighters[1].takeDowns; %>

                    <% totalSubmissionAttempts = totalSubmissionAttempts + fight.fighters[0].submissionAttempts; %>


                    <% if(fight.fighters[0].result == "win") { %>
                        <% totalWin++; %>
                    <% } else if (fight.fighters[0].result == "loss") { %>
                        <% totalLoss++; %>
                    <% } else if (fight.fighters[0].result == "draw") { %>
                        <% totalDraw++; %>
                    <% } else if (fight.fighters[0].result == "nocontest") { %>
                        <% totalNocontest++; %>
                    <% } %>

                    <% if (fight.info.method == "ko") { %>
                        <% totalKO++; %>
                    <% }  else if(fight.info.method == "submission") { %>
                        <% totalSubmission++; %>
                    <% } else if(fight.info.method == "decision") { %>
                        <% totalDecision++; %>
                    <% } %>


                    <% timeInsec =  ((fight.info.round -1)  * 300) +  fight.info.min * 60 + fight.info.sec;%>
                    <% strikeScore = (fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeLanded / (timeInsec * 60))    / (fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeLanded / (timeInsec * 60)) + (fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeLanded / fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeThrow) / (fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeLanded / fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeThrow) + (((fight.info.method == "ko" && fight.fighters[0].result == "win") ? 1 : 0) - 1) * 100; %>

                    <% strikeScoreTotal = strikeScoreTotal + strikeScore; %>


           <% }  else if (fighter.firstName == fight.fighters[1].fighter.firstName && fighter.lastName == fight.fighters[1].fighter.lastName) { %>




                    <% totalTimeinsec = totalTimeinsec + ((fight.info.round -1)  * 300) +  fight.info.min * 60 + fight.info.sec);%> 

                    <% totalSignificantStrikeLanded = totalSignificantStrikeLanded + fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeLanded; %>

                    <% totalSignificantStrikeThrows = totalSignificantStrikeThrows + fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeThrow; %>

                    <% totalStrikeAbsorbed = totalStrikeAbsorbed + fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeLanded; %>

                    <% totalStrikeEnemyThrows = totalStrikeEnemyThrows + fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeThrow; %>

                    <% totalStrikeEnemyLanded = totalStrikeEnemyLanded + fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeLanded; %>

                    <% totalTakeDowns = totalTakeDowns + fight.fighters[1].takeDowns; %>

                    <% totalTakeDownAttempts = totalTakeDownAttempts + fight.fighters[1].takeDownAttempts; %>

                    <% totalTakeDownEnemyAttempts = totalTakeDownEnemyAttempts + fight.fighters[0].takeDownAttempts; %>

                    <% totalTakeDownsEnemyDid = totalTakeDownsEnemyDid + fight.fighter1.takeDowns; %>

                    <% totalSubmissionAttempts = totalSubmissionAttempts + fight.fighters[1].submissionAttempts; %>

                    <% if(fight.fighters[1].result == "win") { %>
                        <% totalWin++; %>
                    <% } else if (fight.fighters[1].result == "loss") { %>
                        <% totalLoss++; %>
                    <% } else if (fight.fighters[1].result == "draw") { %>
                        <% totalDraw++; %>
                    <% } else if (fight.fighters[1].result == "nocontest") { %>
                        <% totalNocontest++; %>
                    <% } %>

                    <% if (fight.info.method == "ko") { %>
                        <% totalKO++; %>
                    <% }  else if(fight.info.method == "submission") { %>
                        <% totalSubmission++ ;%>
                    <% } else if(fight.info.method == "decision") { %>
                        <% totalDecision++; %>
                    <% } %>


                    <% timeInsec =  ((fight.info.round -1)  * 300) +  fight.info.min * 60 + fight.info.sec;%>
                    <% strikeScore = (fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeLanded / (timeInsec * 60))    / (fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeLanded / (timeInsec * 60))  + (fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeLanded / fight.fighters[1].significantStrikeThrow)  / (fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeLanded / fight.fighters[0].significantStrikeThrow) + (((fight.info.method == "ko" && fight.fighters[1].result == "win") ? 1 : 0) - 1) * 100; %>

                    <% strikeScoreTotal = strikeScoreTotal + strikeScore; %>


           <% } %>
           <% }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i see two problem here.

In this line

`<% totalTimeinsec = totalTimeinsec + ((fight.info.round -1)  * 300) + fight.info.min * 60 + fight.info.sec);%>`

Remove `)` before `;`

In this line

`<% totalTimeinsec = totalTimeinsec + ((fight.info.round -1)  * 300) +  fight.info.min * 60 + fight.info.sec);%>`

Again remove `)` before `;`

Hope this helps.